# Does a stack start on 0 or 1?

Tags: java, recursion, stack

So I was curious if I can implement a recursion limit to Java, and discovered this code at the link:
[Set maximum recursion depth in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729546/set-maximum-recursion-depth-in-java/53729795)

What number does getStackTrace().length start counting at? 0 or 1?
What number does a "Stack" start on? 0 or 1?

```
public class RecursionLimiter {
    public static int maxLevel = 10;

    public static void emerge() {
        if (maxLevel == 0)
            return;
        try {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Too deep, emerging");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            if (e.getStackTrace().length > maxLevel + 1)
                throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class RecursionLimiter {
    public static int maxLevel = 10;

    public static void emerge() {
        if (maxLevel == 0)
            return;
        try {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Too deep, emerging");

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            if (e.getStackTrace().length > maxLevel) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace().length);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        printRecursively(8);

    }

    public static void printRecursively(int n) {
        RecursionLimiter.emerge();
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println(1);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(n);
        printRecursively(n-1);


    }
```

I used the above two classes, and it seems to stop working at printRecursively(9) [in main()]; which means the stack has reached 10 already since the exception is thrown.

What is happening in the background?
By running printRecursively() ["first iteration"], is it added on to the stack? Even then shouldn't printRecursively(9) only use 9 "stack levels"?

Comment: Index starts at 0

Comment: @AxelH From what you're saying, I'm getting that while the index starts at 0, it is filled with a "dummy" entry that makes the actual first item index start at 1. Is that correct (also, this applies to every Collection implementation as well).

Comment: Made a typo while writing ! I removed that monstrosity. The length simply count the number of item in the `Stack`. So an empty stack have a length of `0`. When you add an item, that item have an index of `0` and the stack a length of `1`. A new item in it, `length = 2`, `index = 1`

Comment: @AxelH Okay, thanks. It works similar to a normal array then :)

Answer (score 0):

getStackTrace() is a very slow method (which is the reason why Exceptions are regarded as slow). Never use it for normal program flow ([Effective Java, item 57](http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-57-use-exceptions-only-for.html)). If you want to implement a recursion limit, provide a down-counter to the recursed method:

```
public static void printRecursively(int n, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0)
        ... stop recursing

    System.out.println(n);
    printRecursively(n-1, depth - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't think about that aspect (the speed of the application).